# jQuery and Ajax - cannot POST

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, get

I am trying to login to a website using a known username and password and to get some data displayed from the site for a specific user account on that website. I am using jQuery and Ajax for this purpose. This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
async: false,
cache: false,
type: 'POST',
dataType: 'json',  // json...just for example sake
data: ({
    'login_username': username,
    'secretkey': password
}),
url: 'https://mail.someserver.com/src/redirect.php',
success: function (data) {
    alert("SUCCESS!")
    if (data === '1') {  // server returns a "1" for success
        // success!
        // do whatever you need to do
    } else {
        // fail!
    }
},
error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // something went wrong with the request
    alert("Failed!");
}
```

});

I've already made my search around the web and I know that browsers do not permit cross server ajax calls to prevent security issues, but I've already tried to use "jsonp" as dataType to no avail :(

So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What data type you want to receive in php files?

Comment: Please see the updated code. Note that launching the url:
https://mail.someserver.com/src/redirect.php?login_username=someusername&secretkey=somepasswd
works just fine (successfully logins the user)

Comment: Is there any output on the debug console? (On Chrome hit F12 to open the developer tools, right click on the console space, and check "Log XMLHttpRequests").

Comment: using jsonp you have to use callback function. http://www.geekality.net/2010/06/27/php-how-to-easily-provide-json-and-jsonp/

Comment: @Zorayr I am making a Chrome Extension which implements the above code, so I am not sure that console would show would show anything. The console window of background.html which calls background.js which runs the above code shows nothing: http://i.imgur.com/Wuewwkl.png

Comment: try `data: {
    login_username: username,
    secretkey: password
}` instead of `data: ({
    'login_username': username,
    'secretkey': password
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault isn't at the code above, my fault was that in my manifest file (I am building a Google Chrome extension) I didn't have set proper permissions (https://*).

Sorry for the frustration!

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that your `url` is not breaking the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) -- that is, the request coming from the client cannot request data from a server from a different domain (there are exceptions to this rule, namingly [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), but that requires that you make changes to the server/application you're talking to).

The solution to your problem would be to make the request from some server-side script, then in turn having your client application query that script, based on the same machine that's serving the application to the web.

Comment: Please see the updated code. Note that launching the url:
https://mail.someserver.com/src/redirect.php?login_username=someusername&secretkey=somepasswd
works just fine (successfully logins the user)